# Using ASP.Net GridView Update Command for specific fields

Tags: asp.net

How do I use the Update command in GrideView?

I would like to use update command for specific fields in the dataset, but not all fields from database ( or maybe in GridView? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start with some GridView tutorials and post any specific issues that you run into here.

[GridView Tutorial](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/gridview.aspx)

[Simple Insert, Select, Edit, Update and Delete in Asp.Net GridView control](http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/GridView_Insert_Edit_Update_Delete.aspx)